# Can you write values output by a python script to an empty list in another python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

So I have a folder with around 80 .txt files. My current python script iterates through each one of them and calculates a single probability value from the data in each of these files. I need to plot these probabilities against a set of numbers (which I can generate by a simple for loop) and have stored in a list, which lies in another .py file.
Is there any way for me to append each one of these values directly to the empty list in the other .py file?

I was thinking I could keep the empty list in the the .py file and add the corresponding probability value as the script iterates through each file, but I'd like the two to be separate.

Comment: Just append it into a `txt` file then read read the file when you are done, or you can use classes but it is hard to help you with the information given.  Please give a [minimum runable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just realised the same thing a couple of seconds later. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do it that way, but it's much better design to keep the two separate.  Instead, write the data to a new file, and have your final Python file read it from there.

Perhaps easier access is if you use JSON or CSV format: you can write the data with the corresponding Python package, and read it in one easy operation.

If you post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current setup (with, say, a loop over 3 input files), we could give you a few lines of sample code.